# Counting adjacent smaller number in a list with O(n) RunTime?

Tags: python, recursion, stack, runtime, combinatorics

I have been asked to program a function that runs on a list and for every index of it counts the number of values that were smaller than the current on and adjacent to it. for example in index 5 the Value "75" is bigger than 60,70,60.

Input:

```
(100,80,60,70,60,75,85)
```

The system's output :

```
(0,0,0,1,0,3,5)
```

I was asked to do it RunTime of ***O(n)***
and by Using Class Stack. and im pretty clueless.

I'm guessing it has something to do with recursion

solutions in any other language are gonna be very helpfull

Comment: Your question and example aren't very clear. What will be output if there is a '75' at the end?

Comment: For every value in the first list.

Comment: I need to count the numer of values before it that were smaller then him but are ajasent

Comment: To one another. For 75 its 60,70,60

Answer (score 0):

In python it can be done using List which has pop and push methods (as used in stack). Code is some thing like this:

```
a = [100,80,60,70,60,75,85]
out = []
for i in a:
    out.append(len([i for j in a if i>j] ))
print out
```